# Best LINQ-to-XML query to select nodes based on properties of descendant nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FamilyTree>
  <Parent name="Ken">
    <Child name="Lorna">
      <Grandchild name="Andrew"/>
      <Grandchild name="Brian"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Mike">
      <Grandchild name="Ann"/>
      <Grandchild name="Beth"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent name="Norma">
    <Child name="Owen">
      <Grandchild name="Charles"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Peter">
      <Grandchild name="Charlotte"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent name="Quinn">
    <Child name="Robert">
      <Grandchild name="Debbie"/>
      <Grandchild name="Eric"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Susan">
      <Grandchild name="Frank"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent name="Tom">
    <Child name="Ursula">
      <Grandchild name="George"/>
      <Grandchild name="Harriet"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Victor">
      <Grandchild name="Ian"/>
      <Grandchild name="Juliet"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
</FamilyTree>
```

I'm trying to select all the "Parents" with a Child who has at least two children ("Grandchild") of his/her own. Note that I'm *not* looking for "Parents" with at least two "Grandchild[ren]".

The following LINQ query works, but I've a feeling it's not the most elegant.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> parents = (from c in familyTreeElement.Descendants("Child")
                                 where c.Elements().Count() > 1
                                 select c.Parent).Distinct();
```

Is there a better way to specify this?

Comment: First comment - that's checking for at least *two* children...

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the typo. I do indeed want to check for at least two children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh the edit (2 grand-children) helps ;-p

While `XDocument` is useful, at times I miss XPath/XQuery. With `XmlDocument` you could just use `doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Parent[Child/Grandchild[2]]")`.

Comment: Any reason not to use XPathExtensions then?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Typos. Was thinking too hard when trying to explain it all.

Comment: familyTreeElement.XPathSelectElements("Parent[Child/Grandchild[2]]"); seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm... I'm finding it hard to get my head round it exactly :)

Normally to find out if there are *any* elements, I'd use `Any` - but you want to see if there are *at least two* elements. We still don't need to use `Count` though - because there being at least two elements is the same as skipping an element and seeing if there are still any. So...

```
var parents = familyTreeElement.Elements("Parent")
    .Where(parent => parent.Elements("Child").Any(
                     child => child.Elements("Grandchild").Skip(1).Any()));
```

I think that works - and actually it doesn't read *too* badly:

For each parent, see whether *any* of there children has *any* (grand)children after ignoring the first (grand)child.

I suspect using XPath (as per Marc's answer) would be the most readable option though.

Comment: That's a clever way to find whether there are two without counting.  +1.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it before, but it's exactly how we'd do it as humans. If we were asked to make sure there were at least ten biscuits in a tin, we'd only look as far as the first ten we saw :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the "SQL-like" syntax enough to guarantee that I'll get the syntax right if I write it that way, but you want to use `.Any()` instead of `.Count()`, and if you select in a different manner, you don't need the `Distinct()` at the end.  Try this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> parents =
    familyTreeElement.Elements("Parent").Where(
        parent => parent.Elements("Child").Any(
            child => child.Elements().Count() >= 2));
```

**EDIT:**  If you want to ensure that there are at least 2, you do pretty much have to use `.Count()`.

Comment: Count() is for wimps - you can get away without it ;)