# C# Linq to XML, get parents when a child satisfy condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need some help. I have this xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyItems>
    <Parent upc="A00000000000000000000001" sku="" archivo="pantalon1.jpg">
        <Child upc="101" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
            <GrandChild archivo="image##.jpg" />
        </Child>
        <Child upc="102" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
            <GrandChild archivo="image##.jpg" />
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent upc="A00000000000000000000002" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
        <Child upc="101" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
            <GrandChild archivo="image##.jpg" />
        </Child>
        <Child upc="102" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
            <GrandChild archivo="image##.jpg" />
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent upc="200" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
        <Child upc="201" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
            <GrandChild archivo="image##.jpg" />
        </Child>
        <Child upc="202" sku="" archivo="image##.jpg">
            <GrandChild archivo="image##.jpg" />
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</MyItems>
```

Then, I'm trying to select all the 'Parents' where a 'Child' fulfils a condition. Example, all the parents which contains a child where, child attribute upc is equal to `101`

I was studying this article:
[Select nodes based on properties of descendant nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787240/best-linq-to-xml-query-to-select-nodes-based-on-properties-of-descendant-nodes)

But I just can't get what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = ...;
var targetUpc = 101;
var query = doc.Descendants("Parent")
    .Where(p => p.Elements("Child")
                 .Any(c => (int)c.Attribute("upc") == targetUpc)
    );
```

So what the query does is select all descendant elements named `Parent` where any of its child elements named `Child` have an attribute named `upc` that is equal to the target upc value, `targetUpc`.  Hopefully you should be able to follow that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Where` with a nested `Any`.

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(yourString);
var result = xml.Elements("Parent").Where(parent => 
    parent.Elements("Child").Any(child => child.Attribute("upc").Value == "101"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<MyItems>
    <Parent upc=""A00000000000000000000001"" sku="""" archivo=""pantalon1.jpg"">
        <Child upc=""101"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
            <GrandChild archivo=""image##.jpg"" />
        </Child>
        <Child upc=""102"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
            <GrandChild archivo=""image##.jpg"" />
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent upc=""A00000000000000000000002"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
        <Child upc=""101"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
            <GrandChild archivo=""image##.jpg"" />
        </Child>
        <Child upc=""102"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
            <GrandChild archivo=""image##.jpg"" />
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent upc=""200"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
        <Child upc=""201"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
            <GrandChild archivo=""image##.jpg"" />
        </Child>
        <Child upc=""202"" sku="""" archivo=""image##.jpg"">
            <GrandChild archivo=""image##.jpg"" />
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</MyItems>";

            XElement MyItems = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var parents = MyItems.Elements("Parent").Where(parent => parent.Elements("Child").Any(child => child.Attribute("upc").Value == "101"));
            foreach (var parent in parents)
                Console.WriteLine(parent.Attribute("upc").Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely for me:

```
var query =
    from p in XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Elements("Parent")
    where (
            from c in p.Elements("Child")
            where c.Attribute("upc").Value == "101"
            select c
        ).Any()
    select p;
```